# Some Services Are Not Able To Be Constructed identity role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have both `Startup.cs` and `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` in my project. After adding line `.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()` to `IdentityHostingStartup.cs` i get error:

Some services are not able to be constructed

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole] while attempting to activate Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'.

Adding `services.AddScoped/Transient(IRoleStore,RoleManager)` doesnt work cause im getting error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0311?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0311)

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });


            CreateRoles(serviceProvider);
        }

private void CreateRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var roleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
            var userManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            string email = "someEmail";

            Task<IdentityResult> roleResult;
            var adminRoleExists = roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin").Result;       
            if(!adminRoleExists)
            {
                roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
                roleResult.Wait();
            }

            var userRoleExists = roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("User").Result;
            if (!userRoleExists)
            {
                roleResult = roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole("User"));
                roleResult.Wait();
            }

            Task<ApplicationUser> testUser = userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            testUser.Wait();


            if (testUser.Result == null)
            {
                ApplicationUser administrator = new ApplicationUser();
                administrator.Email = email;
                administrator.UserName = email;

                Task<IdentityResult> newUser = userManager.CreateAsync(administrator, "2137jp2gmd");
                newUser.Wait();

                if (newUser.Result.Succeeded)
                {
                    Task<IdentityResult> newUserRole = userManager.AddToRoleAsync(administrator, "Admin");
                    newUserRole.Wait();
                }
            }

        }
```

**IdentityHostingStartup.cs**

```
 public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(
                        context.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AuthDbContextConnection")));

                services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
                {
                    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>();

                
            });
        }
```

Comment: You probably need to call `.AddRoleStore<...>(...)` or similar

Comment: Added ```.AddRoleStore<IdentityRole>()```
Now this error: InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.ISecurityStampValidator Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SecurityStampValidator1[BugTracker.Areas.Identity.Data.ApplicationUser]: Implementation type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole' can't be converted to service type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IRoleStore1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole]'

Answer (score 4):

In **IdentityHostupStartup.cs**

change

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>();
```

To

```
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I dont know why but switching this two lines each other somehow works and everything is fine.